# Emacs function automaticly accepting prompt

Tags: function, emacs, prompt

I am trying to find a way to automatically accept the first proposal from the minibuffer.

```
(defun find-file-at-point-without-prompt ()
(interactive )
(find-file-at-point)
)
```

Calling results in the prompt: "`Find file or URL: ......`". I just want an automatic "yes".

Passing arguments does not work. It might be interesting for other cases as well. I used a macro before that would just call find-file-at-point followed by a RET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no variable to automatically accept the prompt.

You can redefine a function `ffap-read-file-or-url` by removing a part which  is doing the prompt. It remains something like this

```
(defun ffap-read-file-or-url (prompt guess)
  "Read file or URL from minibuffer, with PROMPT and initial GUESS."
  (or guess (setq guess default-directory))
  (let (dir)
    ;; Tricky: guess may have or be a local directory, like "w3/w3.elc"
    ;; or "w3/" or "../el/ffap.el" or "../../../"
    (or (ffap-url-p guess)
    (progn
      (or (ffap-file-remote-p guess)
          (setq guess
            (abbreviate-file-name (expand-file-name guess))
            ))
      (setq dir (file-name-directory guess))))
    ;; Do file substitution like (interactive "F"), suggested by MCOOK.
    (or (ffap-url-p guess) (setq guess (substitute-in-file-name guess)))
    ;; Should not do it on url's, where $ is a common (VMS?) character.
    ;; Note: upcoming url.el package ought to handle this automatically.
    guess))
```

Comment: It is succesful, though the problem is defining something in one of emacs' files. Once you would install a new version, then this would have to be replaced again?

Comment: Well, you redefine the function in your .emacs file which will be there after you upgrade the emacs. Of course, it may happen that in a new version of emacs this function is not compatible (or even doesn't exist). But it's a rare case for old stuff like ffap

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, I can use the advice, but I want to remove the code from ffap-read-file-or-url not add some code. In this case redefining a function is easier IMO

Comment: So redefining this elsewhere is not likely to cause trouble. I was thinking it might have trouble with variables or whatever, not being in said file. But it works, accepted answer!